# Memorable ordinals

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

Suppose $V=L$ + reasonable hypotheses (e.g. "ZFC has a countable transitive model"). Call a countable ordinal $\alpha$ *memorable* if for some countable $\beta$, $\alpha$ is definable *without parameters* in every $L_\gamma$ with $\beta<\gamma<\omega_1$.

My question is:

> Are there uncountably many memorable ordinals?

---

Some comments, right off the bat:

- The answer is trivially "no" for *uniformly* memorable ordinals, that is, ordinals which are coboundedly definable without parameters *by the same formula*. However, since the defining formula is allowed to vary with $\gamma$, this doesn't work.
- Towards a positive answer, note that there are uncountably many countable $\theta$ such that $L_\theta$ is pointwise definable (call such an ordinal "insightful"); this was proved by [Hamkins, Linetsky, and Reitz](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.4597v2.pdf). However, this doesn't actually resolve the issue: for a fixed $\alpha$, there may be many countable $\eta>\alpha$ with no insightful ordinals $>\alpha$ which are definable without parameters in $L_\eta$ (e.g. if there is no greatest insightful ordinal $<\eta$, this seems a distinct possibility).

---

Interestingly, this question has possibly interesting variants even if $L$ is a very tiny subclass of $V$! Given any hierarchy $(M_\alpha)_{\alpha\in\omega_1}$ with $M_\alpha\cap ON=\alpha$, we can ask whether uncountably many $\alpha$ satisfy "For all sufficiently large $\beta<\omega_1$, $\alpha$ is parameter-free definable in $M_\beta$." Now, we can trivially construct examples where the answer is "yes": namely, let $M_\alpha$ be $L_{\eta_\alpha}$ where $\eta_\alpha$ is the $\alpha$th insightful ordinal; so the general existence question isn't interesting. However, I would be curious if there are any "natural" hierarchies of $M_\alpha$s which do satisfy this property; especially if their union is $H_{\omega_1}$ in some $V$ which is very far from $L$.

Comment: I used to remember all those memorable ordinals. But I guess they weren't ***that*** memorable after all... :P

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is a very nice question, but unfortunately, the answer is no.

**Theorem.** There are only countably many memorable ordinals.

**Proof.** Let $\delta$ be a countable ordinal with $L_\delta\prec
L_{\omega_1}$. I claim that every memorable ordinal is less than
$\delta$.

To see this, suppose that $\alpha$ is memorable, as witnessed by
$\beta$. Fix an ordinal $\gamma$ above both $\delta$ and $\beta$ with $L_\gamma\prec
L_{\omega_1}$. It follows that $L_\delta\prec L_\gamma\prec
L_{\omega_1}$. But since $\beta\leq\gamma$, we know $\alpha$ is
definable in $L_\gamma$ and hence (since there are no parameters)
definable in $L_\delta$. So $\alpha<\delta$, as desired. **QED**

Comment: Nice, thank you!

Comment: I think we should aspire to give a characterization of the memorable ordinals.

Comment: Notice that the model $L_\delta$ consists exactly of the definable elements of $L_{\omega_1}$ and hence is itself pointwise definable.

Comment: Since "$\alpha$ is memorable" is first-order expressible in $L_{\omega_1}$, it follows from $L_\delta\prec L_{\omega_1}$ that they must be bounded below $\delta$.

Comment: Indeed, since "$\alpha$ is memorable" is $\Sigma_2$ expressible in $L_{\omega_1}$, they will all be below the first $\delta$ where $L_\delta\prec_{\Sigma_2} L_{\omega_1}$. Perhaps this will be a characterization?

Comment: Hehe, I was just about to ask whether the memorable ordinals could be cofinal in $\delta$! Thinking about the satisfaction relation, is $\prec_{\Sigma_3}$ enough to bound them? (I'm not sure about my quantifier counting.)

Comment: Hah, comment overlap! Yes, I suspect that's a characterization although I don't immediately see how to prove it.

Comment: Clearly, we are thinking in tune here with the overlapping comments.

Comment: Well, I think $L_\delta$ (for $L_\delta\prec L_{\omega_1}$) is right about memorability unless my quantifier counting is off. Given that, the least unmemorable $\gamma$ - being $<\delta$ - will be definable in $L_\delta$. However, since $\delta$ itself isn't memorable, we can't "move this definition up," so this doesn't give a contradiction immediately. Can we get around this?

Comment: Are they closed downwards?

Comment: Hm, I think the least non-$\Sigma_1$-definable ordinal $\theta$ will be memorable. Here's what I'm thinking: for each $\Sigma_1$ formula $\varphi$, let $\beta_\varphi$ be (i) the least $\alpha$ such that $L_\alpha$ sees *two* ordinals satisfying $\varphi$, or (ii) $0$, otherwise. If we take $\gamma=\sup_{\varphi\in\Sigma_1}\beta_\varphi$ plus enough so that $L_\gamma$ sees that every ordinal $<\theta$ *is* $\Sigma_1$-definable, I think every $L_\eta$ with $\eta>\gamma$ sees $\theta$: (cont'd)

Comment: it can tell that everything $<\theta$ isn't $\Sigma_1$-definable, and it sees every other potential $\Sigma_1$ definition of $\theta$ either not hold of $\theta$, or hold of at least two ordinals and hence not define $\theta$. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, I agree. The way I think about it is: the least $\alpha$ that isn't $\Sigma_1$-definable in $L$ is revealed as such once you get above the witnesses required to $\Sigma_1$-define the smaller ordinals. So this defines $\alpha$ in all further $L_\gamma$.

Comment: So we've trapped the memorable ordinals strictly above 1-stable and below 2-stable.

Comment: (Re: your penultimate comment:) I don't quite see that - what if $L_\gamma$ sees a $\Sigma_1$ formula which holds of $\theta$, and thinks it defines $\theta$ since it doesn't see the other solution(s)? I feel like we need to go above just finding witnesses to the smaller ordinals' $\Sigma_1$-definability.

Comment: Oh, I see why you did that now.

Comment: For downward closure: if $\alpha$ is memorable, then eventually in $L_\gamma$ it is definable and also $\alpha$ is countable there. So the L-least real coding $\alpha$ can now be used to define any $\alpha'<\alpha$. So they form an initial segment of the ordinals.

Comment: The $\Sigma_1$-definable objects are eventually defined by the same formula every time.

Comment: I wonder if we can get every $\Delta_2$-definable ordinal as well. The outline I see is the following. Let $\varphi\in\Sigma_2$, $\psi\in\Pi_2$ each define a unique ordinal $\alpha$. Then sufficiently large $\gamma$ see (i) a witness to $\varphi(\alpha)$ and (ii) for each $\beta<\alpha$, a witness to $\neg\psi(\beta)$; so in $L_\gamma$, $\alpha$ is the least ordinal satisfying  $\varphi$. But taking this apart, this relies on all sufficiently large $\gamma$ seeing $\varphi\iff\psi$; so really this only works for "provably" $\Delta_2$ ordinals. Is this fixable?

Comment: I think my remarks about about $2$-stable and $L_\delta\prec_{\Sigma_2} L_{\omega_1}$ should have been instead about $L_\delta\prec_{\Sigma_3} L_{\omega_1}$. We only know that the memorable ordinals are bounded below the least $\Sigma_3$-correct ordinal in $L_{\omega_1}$.

Answer (score 3):

REPAIRED ARGUMENT

The memorables are strictly bounded between the first $\Sigma_2$-stable in $\omega_1$ and the first $\Sigma_3$-stable in $\omega_1$. The least non-memorable is thus a $(\Sigma_2\wedge \Pi_2)$-singleton.

Let $\delta_0$ be this first non-memorable. The previous erroneous argument yields a characterisation or perhaps a paraphrase of $\delta_0$.

For $\beta<\omega_1$ let

(A) $H(\beta)$ be the Skolem Hull inside $L_\beta$ of the empty set.

(B) Let $\omega_1(\beta):= (\omega_1)^{L_\beta}$ if the latter is defined,
              $= \beta$ otherwise.

Then (i) $H(\beta)$ is the set of pointwise definable objects in $L_\beta$. (ii) $H(\omega_1(\beta))=$ $L_\tau$ for some $\tau\leq \omega_1(\beta)$. (iii) For unboundedly many $\beta$, $\beta = \omega_1(\beta)$.

*Claim* Let $\delta_1 =$ the least $\delta< \omega_1$ so that for unboundedly many $\beta$ $H(\beta)=L_{\delta_1}$.  Then $\delta_1=\delta_0$.

Proof: It is easy to argue that $\delta_1$ is defined. Then, by definition $\delta_1$ is not memorable (as $\delta_1
\notin H(\beta)$ for arbitrarily large $\beta$).  So it suffices to show that $\tau<\delta_1 \rightarrow \tau$ is memorable.

By definition, and countability, of $\delta_1$:

$\exists \beta_0\forall \beta> \beta_0\forall\tau<\delta_1\,\, H(\beta)\neq L_\tau \quad (*).$

As $\beta \longrightarrow \omega_1$ so does $\omega_1(\beta) \longrightarrow \omega_1$ non-decreasingly. Thus there is $\beta_1>\beta_0$ so that:

$\forall\beta>\beta_1\,\, \omega_1
(\beta)>\beta_0.$

Then, using (ii), for any $\beta>\beta_1\,\, H(\omega_1(\beta))=L_\gamma$ for some $\gamma \leq\omega_1(\beta)$ but by $(*)$ $\delta_1\leq
\gamma.$   Thus any $\tau< \delta_1$ is pointwise definable in $H(\omega_1(\beta))$ and so (using a definition of $\omega_1$), it is pointwise definable in $L_\beta$. So all $\tau$ less than $\delta_1$ are memorable as required.   $\quad $ QED.

So something similar would work if CH holds, or in CH models. Eg let $A\subseteq\omega_1$ be such that $H_{\omega_1}=L_{\omega_1}[A]$. Consider the least $\delta$ with $L_\delta[A\cap \delta]\prec L_{\omega_1}[A]$.

Comment: Very nice, Philip, thank you for posting!  Your argument seems right, but this causes me to be confused. Isn't "$\alpha$ is memorable" a $\Sigma_2$ expressible assertion in $L_{\omega_1}$? In that case, then if $L_\delta\prec L_{\omega_1}$, there would have to be non-memorable ordinals below $\delta$, which contradicts your theorem. And $\Sigma_3$-correct $\delta$ should be enough for that. What have I got wrong?

Comment: You are of course right, Joel, there have to be non-memorables below $\delta$. My mistake was the final ''Hence'' (I really should check my work! Elementarity in every element of an increasing tower does not imply elementarity in the union.)

Comment: I guess your argument does show:  the supremum of the memorable ordinals is exactly the first ordinal $\tau$ with uncountably many elementary extensions below $L_{\omega_1}$. Right?

Comment: Incidentally, this kind of characterization of an ordinal, in terms of its number and kind of elementary extensions, is here in Bonn referred to as a Welch-style characterization. Peter Koepke had said a few days ago, Perhaps we should aim at a Welch-style characterization, and now you've come through!

Comment: I guess $\tau$ is the least ordinal with uncountably many elementary extensions $L_\tau\prec L_\gamma$, period.

Comment: Lovely! I'm still reading it in detail, but this looks right to me; thanks!

Comment: A corrected (but apologies for a somewhat delayed) argument now deployed. Joel: 'Indeed right' is the answer to your 'Right?' above.